# How could --compression be missing from my wget?

Tags: wget, gzip

I have experience with the Windows version:

> GNU Wget 1.19.4 built on mingw32.

But now on Ubuntu, I have:

> GNU Wget 1.19.4, a non-interactive network retriever.

There is a relatively [new option](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2017-10/msg00007.html) called `--compression` that was added in 1.19.2:

> - New option --compression for gzip Content-Encoding

And in [1.19.4 release notes](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2018-01/msg00007.html) this is also talked about.

When running `wget -h` the `--compression` is missing on the Ubuntu version. How could I get a version that has it, or how do I enable the possibility of using it? When I try to run an actual command it just says:

```
wget: unrecognized option '--compression=auto'
```

Comment: @steeldriver yes, and those changes were merged upstream in wget 1.19.4; but they address the runtime behaviour (`--compression` defaults to `none` even when the build supports it).

Comment: Without this, it downloads some files - like SVG - as .svg.gz and the contents of the file is actually compressed data. The .html files still reference an .svg file iirc. Even if it referenced the .svg.gz file it wouldn't work, at least not when browsing offline, locally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`--compression` is only available if `wget` is built with `zlib` (a library used for compression and decompression). The `wget` package in Debian [didn’t explicitly build-depend on that library](https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/wget), it gets it indirectly, *via* another library, the GNU TLS library; [the Ubuntu build](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wget) drops the latter, and ends up losing support for compression as a result.

You can see this [in the build logs](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/369168633/buildlog_ubuntu-cosmic-amd64.wget_1.19.5-1ubuntu1_BUILDING.txt.gz):

```
checking for ZLIB... no
checking for compress in -lz... no
```

Rebuilding the package to enable `--compression` can be done as follows:

```
cd /tmp
apt source wget
cd wget-1.19.4
apt build-dep wget
apt install zlib1g-dev
dch -n "Rebuild with compression support."
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

This will produce a package in `/tmp`, which you can then install with `dpkg -i`. You might need to adjust the `cd` step above, depending on the version of `wget` your repositories contain. You might also need to add `deb-src` lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, matching your `deb` lines, to be able to download the source code using `apt source`.

Note that enabling compression by default (`--compression=auto`) can have surprising consequences, which is why [the release notes](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2018-01/msg00007.html) mention that

> As it turns out, implementing gzip support is not trivial; especially in the
>   face of many buggy servers that we have to support. Hence, for the time being,
>   connection compression support has been marked as experimental and disabled by
>   default.

See [Debian bug 887910](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=887910) for an example. I filed [Debian bug 907047](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=907047) and [Ubuntu bug 1788608](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/wget/+bug/1788608) asking for a fix; as a result, an explicit dependency on `zlib` was added in version 1.19.5-2 of the Debian package (present in Debian 10 and later), and imported into Ubuntu (19.04 and later).